# Java issue command in command prompt

Tags: java

I have the following class file. This start a command prompt and print the responses. weird thing is after the first print i.e. dir the subsequent doesn't print. Please advice.

```
import java.io.*;
public class JavaApplication14 {
static Process p;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String line;

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
        OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

        String input = "dir";
        input += "\n";
        writer.write(input);
        writer.flush();



        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Stdout: " + line);
        }
         input = "cd..";
        input += "\n";
        writer.write(input);
        writer.flush();
        input = "dir";
        input += "\n";
        writer.write(input);
        writer.close();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Stdout: " + line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication14.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: You don't have a loop in the code to repeat the `dir`ing. What do your use `line` for? It seems to be simply read but not used anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your (first) `while()` loop never terminates:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Stdout: " + line);
}
```

`readLine()` returns `null` when the stream is closed, but since your sub process is still running, the stream never gets closed.

To solve this, you can either move the reading part into a separate thread (which requires additional synchronization), or a simpler solution would be to see if a specific line contents is read, for example if the command line prompt was printed by `cmd.exe`:

```
while ( !(line = reader.readLine()).startsWith("C:\\") ) {
    System.out.println("Stdout: " + line);
}
```

This should work for your particular use case, and might be sufficient to do some learning - for real applications, you might want to have a look into the [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) project.

Comment: There will always be the danger of `readLine()` blocking until there is more input.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Right - personally, I would use a threading approach, but as you write, "... this is a pain point in Java ..."

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do fundamentally asynchronous work from just one thread, using synchronous I/O operations. Your approach is bound to fail.

Specifically, `readLine()` blocks until there is a full line to be read, or until the underlying stream is closed.

You'll have to write quite a bit more code, involving threads, to make this work. This is a pain point in Java.

You could also use the `ProcessBuilder`, especially its `redirectOutput` method with the argument value `INHERIT`, to make the subprocess inherit your main process's `stdout`. In this scenario you won't have the opportunity to analyze the subprocess's output in Java.

Comment: +1 for the [new ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)